# Word for person who eats insects

Tags: single-word-requests

I was reading [this article](http://eatocracy.cnn.com/2010/07/15/the-case-for-eating-insects/) about eating insects. What is a word for a person who does it?

Comment: *insectivore* applies to animals that eat insects.  Fried grasshoppers & chocolate-covered ants: yum yum.

Comment: "Entomophage": scientists will understand you, but the masses will raise their eyebrows at you. "Insectivore": the masses will understand you, but scientists will raise their eyebrows at you.

Comment: Belongs on cooking.SE!

Comment: Biker esp. without a helmet comes to mind. But *Entomophage* is the medical term.

Comment: Bug connoisseur.

Answer (score 14):

The habit is called [entomophagy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entomophagy), so a person doing so would be called an *entomophage*; *entomophagous* is the adjective.

Answer (score 5):

As @GEdgar said, *insectivore*. Humans are animals, after all. But that implies an insect-only diet. *Omnivore* might be more appropriate.

Comment: I tried to eat an Omni once, but I got iron overload.